# Specifying MF mode (to autogenerate fonts) for a specific printer

Tags: texlive, tex-core, metafont

In Metafont the mode definition is used to define dpi and printer specific adjustments on generating the pixelized character images to use for printing.

How could I specify the mode (from a mf file) for a specific printer?

I am using TeX not latex.

I know how to use modes in running mf itself. But how to define the modes.mf file to use and what mode to run while running TeX and letting it autogenerate the fonts.

Comment: This is discussed at some length in chapter 11 of [the Metafont Book](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfbook?lang=en).

Comment: The basic process is that you write a mode file for your specific printer; you write a .mf file for your font, then you actually run `mf` on a file containing `\mode myprinter; input myfont`.